# Postgres function with select

Tags: postgresql

I want to display as a function this:

```
select LoanId, BookId ,(OutDate-InDate)*0.3 as money, OutDate-InDate days 
from loans
where (OutDate-InDate)> 30 and OutDate::varchar(4)='2000';
```

As a input there is only year, as a output should return select.
I tried make function, but it doesn't work.
Any Idea?

Comment: Please share your code and explain exactly what isn't working there.

Comment: Please read the following and add more information to the question so we can help! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to read your mind so I could answer your question.... but it didn't work.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've a table like below

```
create table loan(loanid int,bookid int,outdate date,indate date);
```

and some data like this

```
insert into loan values(1,2,'01-12-2015','01-10-2015'),(1,2,'01-01-2016','08-01-2016');
```

and I use following select query

```
select loanid,bookid,(outdate-indate)*0.3 as "money",outdate-indate as "days"
from loan
where (OutDate-InDate)> 30 and extract(year from outdate)='2015'

loanid bookid money days 
------ ------ ----- ---- 
1      2      18.3  61
```

Now I've a function to do the job that is

```
create or replace function FN_LOAN_DET(in_year  text)
returns table (loanid int,bookid int,money numeric,days int)
as
$$
select loanid,bookid,(outdate-indate)*0.3 as "money",outdate-indate as "days"
from loan
where (OutDate-InDate)> 30 and  extract(year from outdate)=$1
$$
language sql
```

when I call `select * from FN_LOAN_DET('2015')` I'll get

```
loanid bookid money days 
------ ------ ----- ---- 
1      2      18.3  61
```